# IntelliJ Idea won't stop on breakpoints while GWT debugging in Super Dev Mode

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt

I'm trying to debug GWT app. I added GWT Configuration in Run/Debug Configuration window and can run my app with no issues. In Chrome, I can see my Java code and I can setup breakpoints in Chrome debugger; however, I'd like to use Idea to debug instead of Chrome. Is it possible? If yes, what I did miss in my configuration?

I use:

- GWT 2.10.0
- Idea 2022.1.4
- Java 1.8.0_141
- Chrome of latest version

Update 1:
[GWT Debug Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjWBo.png)

[JS Debug Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJVlY.png)

[JS Debug Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6wmy.png)

Comment: Please check short instruction here: https://gist.github.com/hpehl/bd00b22586d0c75d37d5fe7f0cfcd823

Comment: I still can't use Idea to debug client side GWT code. I tried https://gist.github.com/hpehl/bd00b22586d0c75d37d5fe7f0cfcd823 provided by @y.bedrov. First I run GWT in super dev mode using GWT Debug Confgiuration, that I run JavaScript Debug Configuration. In JavaScript Debug console I see a message "No scripts loaded by Chrome". I attached a few screenshots to my initials post. Please have a look if you have a chance. Thanks.

Comment: Are there any errors in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?